# Collection <CALayerArray: 0x1ed8faa0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app crashes some time while removing wait view from screen. Please guide me how can i improve code given below.

---

The wait view is only called when app is downloading something from server. and when it completed download then i call removeWaitView method.

**Exception Type**: NSGenericException

**Reason:**  Collection  was mutated while being enumerated.

```
+(void) removeWaitView:(UIView *) view{
    NSLog(@"Shared->removeWaitView:");
    UIView *temp=nil;
    temp=[view viewWithTag:kWaitViewTag];
    if (temp!=nil) {
        [temp removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

my waitview adding code is

```
 +(void) showWaitViewInView:(UIView *)view withText:(NSString *)text{
   NSLog(@"Shared->showWaitViewWithtag");
   UIView *temp=nil;
   temp=[view viewWithTag:kWaitViewTag];
   if (temp!=nil)
   {
       return;
   }
   //width 110 height 40
   WaitViewByIqbal *waitView=[[WaitViewByIqbal alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,90,35)];
   waitView.center=CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width/2,(view.frame.size. height/2) -15); 
   waitView.tag=kWaitViewTag;    // waitView.waitLabel.text=text;
   [view addSubview:waitView];
   [waitView release]; 
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the full backtrace of the exception. (You can probably Google around if you're not sure how to find this information.)

Comment: How is `removeWaitView` called?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear - a collection (in this case something like an array) is being modified while it is also being enumerated.

In this specific case we are talking about array of layers, or better said, instances of `UIView` which are all backed up by layers.

The modifications happen when you are calling `removeFromSuperview` or `addSubview`. The enumeration can happen anytime during redrawing.

My guess is - you are not calling your methods from the main thread and the main thread is currently redrawing, so you'll get a racing condition.

Solution: call these methods only from the main thread.

Comment: hmm. i always try to call method like these on main thread but it seems to me that you right because this exception can only comes (according to my code) when it is not called from main thread. Am i right?

Comment: @Developer Aaron Haymain's answer is another possible explanation. It should be obvious from your stack trace.

Comment: Very smart analysis. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should get a copy of the array, so you don't risk the chance of it being modified while your code is enumerating it.  Of course this leaves the chance that a new item may be added as a result of the mutation, thus your enumeration will miss that one array item.   Here is an example specific to the title of your question:

```
[[viewLayer.sublayers copy] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            CALayer * subLayer = obj;
            if(subLayer == theLayerToBeDeleted){
                [subLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
            }

        }];
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that you're adding or removing a the waitView while iterating through the waitView's siblings (it's superView's subviews).  Check to see what methods call `removeWaitView` and `showWaitInView` to make sure the calling methods don't call the show/remove wait view methods from within a for loop iterating the wait view's siblings (the waitView's superview's subviews).

Comment: yes, this can create problem if i had used in a loop no i am not using it in a loop. As i had edited my question, Thanks for information

Comment: Glad to help.  Usually, explicit mutation from within a loop is the most common culprit.  But the mutation can also occur from another thread (which @sulthan pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

To fix issue just start from last element

```
NSMutableArray* Items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[_ScrollList.documentView subviews]];
while ([Items count]>0) {
    NSView *v = [Items lastObject];
    [v removeFromSuperview];
    [Items removeLastObject];
}
```